# Reasons to rename property to _property

Tags: python, coding-style

I was reading source code of `collections.py` yesterday.

In the `namedtuple` function, a `template` string is generated and then `exec`ed in a temporary namespace.

In the namespace dict, `property` is renamed to `_property` and `tuple` to `_tuple`.

I wonder what's the reason behind this. What problems does this renaming helps avoid?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In general, the underscore names are sometimes used in the standard library to to keep a namespace clean.

In the case of _tuple, it was necessary because you're allowed to use "tuple" as a field name:

```
>>> Example = namedtuple('Example', ['list', 'tuple', 'property'])
>>> e.list
[10, 20, 30]
>>> e.tuple
(40, 50, 60)
>>> e.property
'Boardwalk'
```

Comment: @JBernardo, you know RH is one of the Python core developers right? I mean yeah, he _could_ be wrong about this, but I suspect he's speaking from experience.

Comment: So I'm not far off saying I want "with", "as" and "except" as fieldnames then? :)

Comment: @JonClements Those are considered `keywords` and `namedtuple` will raise `ValueError` on them or replace them if `rename` is set to `True`.

Comment: @RaymondHettinger Thanks. Field names can not start with underscore, so the renaming helps avoid situations like `property = property(_itemgetter(0), doc='Alias for field number 0')`

Answer (score 0):

It avoids keyword name conflicts.

Say we had an imaginary list of `['when', 'who', 'why', 'where', 'with']`

ie. one can't type `my_name_tuple.with` without the interpreter going ouch.

Read the docs on the namedtuple thoroughly and you should get it.

Comment: In Python2.7 you can set `rename=True` so that invalid names like `with` will be replaced with something like `_4`. Going ouch or not, this will not affect statement like `x = property(...)` which is executed in the class definition context.